# GitLab CE upgrade fails

Tags: gitlab

I'm trying to upgrade my GitLab CE version running on Kubernets from version 9.3.2-ce.0 to version 11.1.4-ce.0. However, I keep getting this error:

```
================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/default.rb
================================================================================

RuntimeError
------------
Removed configurations found in gitlab.rb. Aborting reconfigure.

Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/package/libraries/omnibus_helper.rb:109:in `check_deprecations'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/default.rb:28:in `from_file'

[...]

System Info:
------------
chef_version=13.6.4
platform=ubuntu
platform_version=16.04
ruby=ruby 2.4.4p296 (2018-03-28 revision 63013) [x86_64-linux]
program_name=/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chef-client
executable=/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chef-client


Running handlers:
There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:

Removed configurations found in gitlab.rb. Aborting reconfigure.


Removals:
* git_data_dir has been deprecated since 8.10 and was removed in 11.0. Use git_data_dirs instead.

Running handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 05 seconds
```

One line is obvious:

```
git_data_dir has been deprecated since 8.10 and was removed in 11.0. Use git_data_dirs instead.
```

However, I have `git_data_dir` absolutely nowhere in my configs. In `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`, I have this line (the only non-commented line):

```
git_data_dirs({ "default" => { "path" => "/gitlab-data/git-data/repositories", 'gitaly_address' => 'unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/gitaly.socket' } })
```

It is obviously in the correct format. I have run `$ gitlab-ctl reconfigure` and the proper paths are provided in the `/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/gitlab.yml` contains the same information.

I cannot for the love of me find out why this upgrade fails. Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Actually, I forgot a step.
All I had to run after changing the config file regarding the git_data_dirs Syntax was:
`gitlab-ctl reconfigure`
After that yum finished without any problems.